# Should I inject ServiceStack's ICacheManager?

Tags: c#, servicestack, autofac

I'm looking to implement a caching tier in our application and accidentally came across ServiceStack's ICacheManager.

`ICacheManager.Resolve` looks as though it's exactly what I'm after (try and get, if it's not in the cache then call the function to get and store it). All documentation I can find however is about using ICacheClient.

How I can wire up ICacheManager using AutoFac? I assume I need to wire up a client e.g.:

```
_builder.Register(c => new MemoryCacheClient())
        .As<ICacheClient>();
```

But then I'm not sure what ICacheManager should resolve to.

Is this a good idea or am I abusing ServiceStack?

I've added a custom cache manager for the time being but it feels wrong for some reason:

```
public class CacheManager : ICacheManager
{
    public CacheManager(ICacheClient cacheClient)
    {
        CacheClient = cacheClient;
    }

    public void Clear(IEnumerable<string> cacheKeys)
    {
        Clear(cacheKeys.ToArray());
    }

    public void Clear(params string[] cacheKeys)
    {
        CacheClient.ClearCaches(cacheKeys.ToArray());
    }

    public ICacheClient CacheClient { get; private set; }

    public T Resolve<T>(string cacheKey, Func<T> createCacheFn) where T : class
    {
        return Resolve(cacheKey, new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0), createCacheFn);
    }

    public T Resolve<T>(string cacheKey, TimeSpan expireIn, Func<T> createCacheFn) where T : class
    {
        var cacheResult = CacheClient.Get<T>(cacheKey);
        if (cacheResult != null)
            return cacheResult;

        var item = createCacheFn();
        CacheClient.Set(cacheKey, item, expireIn);
        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using ServiceStack, you could also use its IoC-Container, so that you could use the registrations for other ServiceStack-components as well.

Comment: Why do you need a CacheManager in the first place? Are you going to have different cache mechanisms depending on the Type?